# Remove html elements with JS

Tags: javascript

I am doing a class exercise.

I have to create an onclick function that remove the elements

that are inside the form

```
 <div id="content">
      <form id="form">
          <p>Hola</p>
          <p>que</p>
          <p>tal</p>     
      </form>
 </div>
```

I need to remove the p elements with js.

I was doing something like this, but tbh I do not know how to do it

```
 document.getElementById('form').appendChild("");
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('form').innerHTML = '';` instead. The innerHTML attribute get and set the inner html of the element as a string.

Answer (score 1):

A single child can be removed by calling the native [Node.removeChild(child)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) method on it's parent. Wrapping this method in a while loop enables you to remove every child of a specified parent node:

```js
function removeAllChildren(parent) {
  while(parent.firstChild) {
    parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild)
  }
}

// usage:
const form = document.getElementById('form');
removeAllChildren(form);
```

As written in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild):

> If the return value of removeChild() is not stored, and no other
> reference is kept, it will be automatically deleted from memory after
> a short time.

This is why this approach is far superior compared to the simpler `parent.innerHTML = ''` method, which could lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation: `document.querySelector('.remove-p-tags-button')` selects your button and `addEventListener` attaches a function/event listener to that button whenever it's clicked. Inside the call back for the `addEventListener` it selects all the p tags within the form and removes them.

```js
document.querySelector('.remove-p-tags-button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('#form p').forEach(el => el.remove());
});
```

```html
 <div id="content">
    <form id="form">
       <p>Hola</p>
       <p>que</p>
       <p>tal</p>     
   </form>
   <button class="remove-p-tags-button">Remove P tags</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) to fetch and [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) to remove selected elements from `DOM`.

```js
function removePTags() {
  document.querySelectorAll("#form p").forEach(e => e.remove());
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <form id="form">
    <p>Hola</p>
    <p>que</p>
    <p>tal</p>
  </form>

  <button onclick="removePTags()">Remove p</button>
</div>
```